# Swift: Switch between two optional values

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode11.4, swift5

I'm trying to implement a switch between two option values:

```
import UIKit

var numOne: Int?
var numTwo: Int?

func doSomething() {
    switch (numOne, numTwo) {
    case (!nil, nil):
        print("something")
    case (_ == _):
        print("equal")
    default:
        break
    }
}

doSomething()
```

But I'm getting this errors:

In the first case I'm getting this error:

`'nil' is not compatible with expected argument type 'Bool'`

in the second case I'm getting this other error:

`Expression pattern of type 'Bool' cannot match values of type '(Int?, Int?)'`

My question for you guys is how can I manage to generate the cases between this to optional values?

I'll really appreciate your help

Answer (score 7):

There's nothing wrong here; the syntax is just incorrect.

For the first case you mean:

```
case (.some, .none):
```

There's no such things as `!nil`. Optionals are not Booleans. You could also write `(.some, nil)` since `nil` is an alias for `.none`, but that feels confusing.

For the second case you mean:

```
case _ where numOne == numTwo:
```

The point here is you mean all cases (`_`) where a condition is true (`where ...`).

---

```
func doSomething() {
    switch (numOne, numTwo) {
    case (.some, .none):
        print("something")
    case _ where numOne == numTwo:
        print("equal")
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: If I want to have this cases `case (.some, .some):` and `case _ where numOne == numTwo:` and this are the values `numTwo = 1 numOne = 1`. Only checks for the first cases.

Comment: Correct. The first case that succeeds is the only one matched in a `switch` statement. That's how `switch` works. If you want the `==` to be applied first, you should order it first. If you want both, you should use `if`, not `switch`. The point of `switch` is to execute exactly one `case`.